# wget refuses to download a file over https, but http works fine

Tags: ssl, https, wget

If I download a file from an HTTP URL, it is all OK and `system("wget -O filename http://www.example.com")` downloads the file.
If I try to download a file from a HTTPS URL only (so I cannot reach it using HTTP) using `system("wget -O filename https://www.example2.com")`, wget gives me an error:

> "Impossible to verify the certificate of URL, released by "CERTIFICATE AUTORITY name": Impossible to verify locally the authority of the issuer.
>   Impossible to establish a SSL connection."

The site doesn't require a password, in fact if I digit "https://www.example2.com/filename" in the browser, it downloads the file.
What should I do?
I want to underline that the browser cannot reach "http://www.example2.com/filename" and it doesn't download the file, but if I digit "https://www.example2.com/filename", the browser downloads the file. So HTTPS only.

Comment: try `--auth-no-challenge` and/or `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: Removing the C tag as the question is not really about C.

Comment: This is not about programming. `system` is a red herring. Read the documentation of `wget`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `--no-check-certificate` option is what you are looking for.

Check the [HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html)

Comment: It doesn't help me. wget doesn't still download the file

Comment: A bit. it says that it isn't possible to verify the certificate of the website, released by Autority certificate name.
And then it send a HTTP request. But my site is reachable using HTTPS only